# `ui-router` $stateParams vs. $state.params

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

With `ui-router`, it's possible to inject either `$state` or `$stateParams` into a controller to get access to parameters in the URL. However, accessing parameters through `$stateParams` only exposes parameters belonging to the state managed by the controller that accesses it, and its parent states, while `$state.params` has all parameters, including those in any child states.

Given the following code, if we directly load the URL `http://path/1/paramA/paramB`, this is how it goes when the controllers load:

```
$stateProvider.state('a', {
     url: 'path/:id/:anotherParam/',
     controller: 'ACtrl',
  });

$stateProvider.state('a.b', {
     url: '/:yetAnotherParam',
     controller: 'ABCtrl',
  });

module.controller('ACtrl', function($stateParams, $state) {
   $state.params; // has id, anotherParam, and yetAnotherParam
   $stateParams;  // has id and anotherParam
}

module.controller('ABCtrl', function($stateParams, $state) {
   $state.params; // has id, anotherParam, and yetAnotherParam
   $stateParams;  // has id, anotherParam, and yetAnotherParam
}
```

The question is, why the difference? And are there best practices guidelines around when and why you should use, or avoid using either of them?

Comment: Such an excellently illustrated question - thank you for telling me even what I was trying to ask!

Answer (score 67, accepted):

The documentation reiterates your findings here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#stateparams-service

If my memory serves, `$stateParams` was introduced later than the original `$state.params`, and seems to be a simple helper injector to avoid continuously writing `$state.params`.

I doubt there are any best practice guidelines, but context wins out for me. If you simply want access to the params received into the url, then use `$stateParams`. If you want to know something more complex about the state itself, use `$state`.

Comment: I found myself using `$state.params` in `ACtrl`, because I wanted to check if `yetAnotherParam` is set. So that if it isn't, I can do something. I'm not going into the details of that _something_ as it could warrant a question of its own. However, I feel I may be doing a _hack_ by checking for a parameter that is introduced by a child state and not recognised by the current state through `$stateParams`. I've found an alternative approach since.

Comment: Actually, the difference between the two is more than just a matter of context. $stateParams captures url-based params that $state considers applies to that state, *even if its child state contains more params*. $state.params seems to capture all url + non-url based params of the **current state** you are in. If you are in state `parent.child`, then `$stateParams` in `parentController` will evaluate url-based params of `parent`, but not those of `parent.child`. See [this issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/136).

Comment: On the other hand, $stateParams can preserve custom objects, types, etc. while $state.params would "convert custom objects into plain objects".

Comment: `$stateParams` works in resolve, while `$state.params` is incorrect (not showing params for state that is not resolved yet)

Comment: I found that the scope can $watch $state.params, but not $stateParams. I have no idea why.

Comment: I am guessing that is because `$state.params` is not a top level object, whereas `$stateParams` is.

Comment: $stateParams was deprecated in 1.0.0
https://gist.github.com/christopherthielen/c275b656f5b8bee81d327a68c809aa7b

Comment: ```module.controller('ABCtrl', function($stateParams, $state) {
   $state.params; // has id, anotherParam, and yetAnotherParam
   $stateParams;  // has id, anotherParam, and yetAnotherParam
}```


@MattWay According to the documentation you linked, the stateParams of ABCtrl should have only yetAnotherParam.

Answer (score 19):

Another reason to use `$state.params` is for non-URL based state, which (to my mind) is woefully underdocumented and very powerful.

I just discovered this while googling about how to pass state without having to expose it in the URL and [answered a question elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23940573/20595) on SO.

Basically, it allows this sort of syntax:

```
<a ui-sref="toState(thingy)" class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="thingy in thingies">{{ thingy.referer }}</a>
```

Comment: Hi bbrown, somehow i can’t make it work, do you have an working example?

Answer (score 14):

EDIT: This answer is correct for version `0.2.10`. As @Alexander Vasilyev pointed out it doesn't work in version `0.2.14`.

Another reason to use `$state.params` is when you need to extract query parameters like this:

```
$stateProvider.state('a', {
  url: 'path/:id/:anotherParam/?yetAnotherParam',
  controller: 'ACtrl',
});

module.controller('ACtrl', function($stateParams, $state) {
  $state.params; // has id, anotherParam, and yetAnotherParam
  $stateParams;  // has id and anotherParam
}
```

Comment: Not applicable anymore.
See Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/r2JhV4PcYpKJdBCwHIWS?p=preview

Answer (score 4):

There are many differences between these two. But while working practically I have found that using  `$state.params` better. When you use more and more parameters this might be confusing to maintain in `$stateParams`. where if we use multiple params which are not URL param `$state` is very useful

```
 .state('shopping-request', {
      url: '/shopping-request/{cartId}',
      data: {requireLogin: true},
      params : {role: null},
      views: {
        '': {templateUrl: 'views/templates/main.tpl.html', controller: "ShoppingRequestCtrl"},
        'body@shopping-request': {templateUrl: 'views/shops/shopping-request.html'},
        'footer@shopping-request': {templateUrl: 'views/templates/footer.tpl.html'},
        'header@shopping-request': {templateUrl: 'views/templates/header.tpl.html'}
      }
    })
```

Answer (score 3):

I have a root state which resolves sth. Passing `$state` as a resolve parameter won't guarantee the availability for `$state.params`. But using `$stateParams` will.

```
var rootState = {
    name: 'root',
    url: '/:stubCompanyId',
    abstract: true,
    ...
};

// case 1:
rootState.resolve = {
    authInit: ['AuthenticationService', '$state', function (AuthenticationService, $state) {
        console.log('rootState.resolve', $state.params);
        return AuthenticationService.init($state.params);
    }]
};
// output:
// rootState.resolve Object {}

// case 2:
rootState.resolve = {
    authInit: ['AuthenticationService', '$stateParams', function (AuthenticationService, $stateParams) {
        console.log('rootState.resolve', $stateParams);
        return AuthenticationService.init($stateParams);
    }]
};
// output:
// rootState.resolve Object {stubCompanyId:...}
```

Using "angular": "~1.4.0", "angular-ui-router": "~0.2.15"

Answer (score 2):

An interesting observation I made while passing previous state params from one route to another is that $stateParams gets hoisted and overwrites the previous route's state params that were passed with the current state params, but using `$state.param`s doesn't.

When using `$stateParams`:

```
var stateParams        = {};
stateParams.nextParams = $stateParams; //{item_id:123}
stateParams.next       = $state.current.name;

$state.go('app.login', stateParams);
//$stateParams.nextParams on app.login is now:
//{next:'app.details', nextParams:{next:'app.details'}}
```

When using $state.params:

```
var stateParams        = {};
stateParams.nextParams = $state.params; //{item_id:123}
stateParams.next       = $state.current.name;

$state.go('app.login', stateParams);
//$stateParams.nextParams on app.login is now:
//{next:'app.details', nextParams:{item_id:123}}
```

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://danubilla.com/blog/web-development/angularui-router-and-injecting-state-vs-stateparams.html) in this article is clearly explained: The `$state` service provides a number of useful methods for manipulating the state as well as pertinent data on the current state. The current state parameters are accessible on the `$state` service at the params key. The `$stateParams` service returns this very same object. Hence, the `$stateParams` service is strictly a convenience service to quickly access the params object on the `$state` service.

As such, no controller should ever inject both the `$state` service and its convenience service, `$stateParams`. If the `$state` is being injected just to access the current parameters, the controller should be rewritten to inject `$stateParams` instead.