# Use $stateParams in parent resolve

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I load a list of recipes before I want to load my page. I need this list in any child state. Depending on the `$stateParam` I want to pre-filter this list.

**Questions**

1. Can I access the `$stateParam` in any way from the parent state?
2. Is it a better design to use a service and load the data in the child state and pass it via the service (where are disadvantages)?

*I avoided the second solution because the resolve allowed me to switch between the child states without reloading the data (or without checking if the data has been loaded yet).*

**Research**
I'm aware that a parent state does not know anything what happens in the child state. But the child state knows of variables in the parent state. I guess this is what this solution used:
[angular ui-router and accessing child state params from parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24301754/angular-ui-router-and-accessing-child-state-params-from-parent)

But I didn't get it working and also I don't want to have a url for the parent state because it is never loaded solo.

**Code**

```
  .state "widget",
    templateUrl: "app/widget/widget.html"
    controller: "WidgetCtrl"
    resolve:
      Recipes: ($http, $stateParams) ->
        console.log "$stateParams.oldContext #{$stateParams.oldContext}"
        return $http.get('/getProovenRecipes').then( (result) ->
          #console.log result.data
          return result.data
        )
  .state "widget.recipes",
    views:
      'recipes':
        templateUrl: "app/widget/recipes/recipes.html"
        controller: "RecipesCtrl"
        controllerAs: "recipesController"
  .state "widget.recipes.tags",
    url: "/widget/{context}"
    views:
      'tags@widget':
        templateUrl: "app/widget/tags/tags.html"
        controller: "TagCtrl"
        controllerAs: "tagController"
```

Comment: How your  present code "does not work"? Little more detail there would help in answering..

Comment: Without using a url in the parent: The console.log returns `undefined` when trying the example in the research link, e.g. `widget/blablub?oldContext=aaaa`. When using a url in the parent state: it just does not work at all and redirects me. Lets say I have not any idea how to access the $stateParam in the `resolve` .

Comment: just guessing:  could you inject $state and access $state.params instead of $stateParams (inspired from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23081397/ui-router-stateparams-vs-state-params)

Comment: In tried that and the weird thing is that `console.log $state` shows me the params including my param I pass. But as soon as I `console.log $state.params` I get an empty object.

Comment: Do you mean [Object]?

Comment: No just `{}`and in the other case I see the params and I'm able to expand them.