# how to send value of variable from ajax to another controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-controller

here is my controller:

```
.controller('loginCtrl', ['$scope',  '$window', '$cookies', '$http', function($scope, $window, $cookies, $http) {
    var frm = $('#loginForm');
    frm.submit(function(ev) {
        var now = new Date();
        now.setTime(now.getTime() + (600000 * 5));
        $.ajax({
            type: frm.attr('method'),
            url: frm.attr('action'),
            //dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: JSON.stringify(frm.serializeObject()),
            success: function(data, textStatus, request) {
                if (request.status == 202) {
                    $cookies.put('diprLogin', 'admin', {
                        expires: now
                    });
                    $window.location.href = '#';  
                    **var roleValue=data[0].role;**
                    console.log(roleValue);
                    $scope.$apply(function() {
                        $scope.noty.add({
                            type: 'info',
                            title: 'Welcome. Admin'
                        });
                    });
                }
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorMessage) {
                $scope.$apply(function() {
                    $scope.noty.add({
                        type: 'danger',
                        title: 'Authentication failed',
                        body: 'Please try again...'
                    });
                });
            }
        });
        ev.preventDefault();
    });    
}]) //End loginCtrl
```

I want to send `roleValue` to every controllers to check some validation. Please help me in figuring how to do this.
Also, can i call ajax from another controllers to return this variable?

Comment: Put it in a service. And access it fron other controllers.

Comment: Replace the jQuery `$.ajax` method with the Angular $http service. It returns promises which are better suited for sharing asynchronously obtained data. And it is better integrated with the AngularJS framework and its digest cycle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try these steps it will work :**

**Step 1 :** Create a service.

```
angular.module('app').service('dataStoreService', function() {
    var data = '';
    function setData(newData){
        data = newData;
    }

    function getData(){
        return data;
    }
})
```

**Step 2 :** In your ajax call you can set the `roleValue` into the service.

```
dataStoreService.setData(roleValue);
```

**Step 3 :** Inject the `dataStoreService` as a dependency in the controllers where you want to get the `roleValue`. and call `getData` function of the `dataStoreService` from controller.

```
dataStoreService.getData();
```

Answer (score 0):

### Option 1

`$localStorage`

You can set the role value in local storage in your current controller  and get the local storage value from another controller for check the condition

controller 1

```
$localStorage.set("role",role);
```

controller 2

```
if($localStorage.get(role)!=1)
{
return false;
}
..
.
.
// next code
```

### Option 2

`$sccokieStore`

It will be works like Same as $localstorage,

### Option 3

`$service`

You can assign the role value on service scope object. whenever you need to check that. you call that service and do it the authentication

### Option 3

`$Broadcast`

**it's one of the best option to do the authentication** . It dispatches an event name downwards to all child scopes (and their children) and notify to the registered `$rootScope.Scope` listeners. The event life cycle starts at the scope on which `$broadcast` was called. All listeners for the event on this scope get notified. Afterwards, the event traverses downwards toward the child scopes and calls all registered listeners along the way. The event cannot be canceled.

You can do authentication in globally like `app.run` side check the current rout and validate the authentication then redirect the route/ not.

More details : [Why do we use $rootScope.$broadcast in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24830679/why-do-we-use-rootscope-broadcast-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways . Yes of course you can store values to `cookies` or `local-storage`. This two would be best option if you need to reuse the values in multiple controller . But if you will use the values once the best option would be to use `$stateParams` or `$state` if your are using ui router [see the difference between the two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23081397/ui-router-stateparams-vs-state-params) . Another option would be to use `$rootScope`.