# $stateParams conflict with $state when passimg parameter with $state.go

Tags: angularjs

I´m want to send parameters with `$state.go` as:

```
 var catPadre = $scope.catalogoPadre;
$state.go("root.catalogosgenericos", catPadre);
```

And I passing as parameter as:

```
 .state('root.catalogosgenericos', {
                 url: "catalogosGenericos.html/",
                 templateUrl: "../SPA/administrador/catalogos/catalogosGenericos.html",
                 controller: "catalogosGenericosCtrl",
                 params: {
                     catPadre: null  
                 },
                 authenticate: true
             })
```

Into angular controller  I injected dependencies like this:

```
  function catalogosGenericosCtrl($scope, apiService, notificationService, $rootScope, $location, $http, $state, $filter) {
```

problem occurs when I use add $stateParams just like:

```
 function catalogosGenericosCtrl($scope, apiService, notificationService, $rootScope, $location, $stateParams, $http, $state, $filter) {
```

It throwing issue in console saying:

> $state is undefined

I don´t understand what is wrong, why  my `$stateParams` conflict `$state` definition. Can someone explain me please?

Comment: This may answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/23081397/215552

Comment: I dont see any problem can you share some plnkr or fiddle to see the error.

Comment: I rewrite my question, can you check it please ? @JesusCarrasco

Comment: @Ledwing var catPadre = $scope.catalogoPadre;
$state.go("root.catalogosgenericos", catPadre); should be $state.go('root.catalogosgenericos', {catPadre: $scope.catalogoPadre}); or $state.go('root.catalogosgenericos',{catPadre: catPadre}'); based on the variable catPadre. Check changing on those notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using below solution:

```
 var catPadre = $scope.catalogoPadre;
$state.go("root.catalogosgenericos", {catPadre:$scope.catalogoPadre});
```

In your route file change the code like below:

```
 .state('root.catalogosgenericos', {
                 url: "/catalogosGenericos/ :catPadre",
                 templateUrl: "../SPA/administrador/catalogos/catalogosGenericos.html",
                 controller: "catalogosGenericosCtrl",

                 authenticate: true
             })
```

Change your controller function:

```
function catalogosGenericosCtrl($scope, apiService, notificationService, $rootScope, $location,  $http, $state,$stateParams, $filter) {
```