# Angular UI-Router passing data between states with go function does not work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui

I just started learning angularjs and I am using angular-ui-router. I am trying to send data from one state to another using `$state.go` but I have no success. Here is what I have so far:

*I have not included the html intentionally because I assumed it was not needed if it is needed please tell me and I will add it.*

I have configured my states as below:

```
  $stateProvider
        .state('public', {
            abstract: true,
            templateUrl: 'App/scripts/main/views/PublicContentParent.html'
        })
        .state('public.login', {
            url: '/login',
            templateUrl: 'App/scripts/login/views/login.html',
            controller: 'loginCtrl'
        })

    $stateProvider
        .state('private', {
            abstract: true,
            templateUrl: 'App/scripts/main/views/PrivateContentParent.html'
        })
        .state('private.visits', {
            url: '/visits',
            views: {
                'main': {
                    controller: 'visitsListCtrl',
                    templateUrl: 'App/scripts/visits/views/VisitsList.html'
                }
            }
        });
```

When my `LoginController` is invoked it will execute  the below code:

```
loginModule.controller('loginCtrl', ['$state', function ($scope, $state) {

    $state.go('private.visits', { name : "Object"});

}]);
```

When the `private.visits` page is active, I am trying to print the `$stateParams`:

```
visitsModule.controller('visitsListCtrl', ['$stateParams',
    function ($stateParams) {

        console.log($stateParams);


    }]);
```

As things state $stateParams is an empty object. I expected it to to contain the object I passed in loginCtrl.

**EDIT**

It seems that if `private.visits` url has this url format `'/visits/:name'` and I also add the property params: ["name"] I get access to the object I send from the `public.login` state.
The side  effect is that the parameters are added to the url which is logical.

I tried doing the same thing with a child state with no url, and in this case it seems that I do not have access to the params I passed from `public.login`.

How do I send data in child states?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

What you have to do is to define the `name` param in the `private.visits` state like:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('public', {
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: 'App/scripts/main/views/PublicContentParent.html'
    })
    .state('public.login', {
        url: '/login',
        templateUrl: 'App/scripts/login/views/login.html',
        controller: 'loginCtrl'
    })

$stateProvider
    .state('private', {
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: 'App/scripts/main/views/PrivateContentParent.html'
    })
    .state('private.visits', {

        // NOTE!
        // Previously, we were only passing params as an array 
        // now we are sending it as an object. If you 
        // send this as an array it will throw an error 
        // stating id.match is not a function, so we updated 
        // this code. For further explanation please visit this
        // url http://stackoverflow.com/a/26204095/1132354
        params: {'name': null}, 

        url: '/visits',
        views: {
            'main': {
                controller: 'visitsListCtrl',
                templateUrl: 'App/scripts/visits/views/VisitsList.html',
                resolve: {
                        name: ['$stateParams', function($stateParams) {
                            return $stateParams.name;
                        }]
                    }
            }
        }
    });
```

And then in the controller access to the name:

```
visitsModule.controller('visitsListCtrl', ['name',
function (name) {
    console.log(name);
}]);
```

Hope it help you!

Comment: This is good answer with clear example, should be the accepted one.

Comment: Can we pass an Object instead of primitive data types ?

Comment: No, you can use JSON.stringify but I recommend to use a factory for sharing the data.

Comment: In this [issue thread](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/928) it recommends using `params: { name: {} }` instead; the params array notation appears broken

Answer (score 3):

When you say:
   `$state.go('private.visits', { name : "Object"});`

You're not passing data to the `private.visits` state, but rather you're setting a parameter to the `private.visits` state, which doesn't even support parameters as you have not defined parameters for it in the state config. If you want to share data between states use a service, or if your states have a parent-child relationship then the child state will have access to the parent states data. Seeing as how you don't want the data to sow up in your URLs, I would use a service (getters/setters) to achieve this.

Comment: You dont think parameters is data? Leaves me puzzled.

Comment: The parameters you pass to a state via the URL are primitive types, and are rendered as strings, the OP wanted to pass an object, @Leandro Zubrezki's answer is correct but there is a difference, using params with ui-router allows to pass in objects (this can be considered as 'data' more than route parameters). But yes, Leonardo's answer is better than mine.

Comment: For some reason, ui-router will filter out that parameters object and only include those whose names match path parameters for the state.  So, since name isn't a path parameter, it is being stripped out.