# passing objects from view to view in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

How I can pass object from page to page with $stateProvider in angularjs? Can you give me some code snippet? I'm new in angular

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide your question with an example code.

Answer (score 1):

When defining a state you have a few options:

```
.state('my-state', {
    url: '/my-state',
    templateUrl: 'my-state-url',
    params: {
        myProperty: 'some value',
    }
})
```

Then you can do this while changing state:

```
$state.go('my-state', {myProperty: 'new value'});
```

In the state controller you can access the `myProperty` like so:

```
$scope.myProperty = $stateParams.myProperty;
```

But depending on the data you want to pass, a custom angular service can/should be used. There's a good tutorial regarding this subject [here](https://thinkster.io/a-better-way-to-learn-angularjs/services).

Comment: so there is no possibility to pass object as parameteres, only via service?

Answer (score 0):

You don't pass the object, you pass the object's ID which will allow you to retrieve the object.

You should use ui-router for this.

When definining states you will define the URL as something like ...

```
"url": '/an/example/path/:objectid',
"controller": "YourControllerForThisView",
```

USE OF THE COLON DEFINES THAT THIS IS A VARIABLE PARAMETER

Then in your controller you can access

state.params.objectid

Then in your controller you will call a method like ...

```
myService.getObjectFromList(state.params.objectid)
```

OR

```
myService.getObjectFromHttpCall(state.params.objectid)
```

to populate the object to be used when rendering the view

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to "pass" objects only between a few (e.g., two or three) views, then using `$stateProvider` would suffice. However, if the same objects shall be retrieved/modified by several different parts of the application, it would be better to place these objects in a service.

For instance, a factory may be created to store such an object.

```
(function () {
    angular.module('myApp').
        factory('myFactory', myFactory);

    function myFactory() {
        var object ={};

        var service = {
            getObject: getObject,
            setObject: setObject,
            setObjectProperty: setObjectProperty
        };
        return service;

        function getObject() {
            return object
        }

        function setObject(newObject) {
            //Some modification logic here
            object = newObject;
            return object;
        }

        function setObjectProperty(property, value) {
            //Modify/assign new object property here
            return object;
        }
    }
})();
```

A controller can then use the factory to retrieve/modify the stored object.

```
(function () {
    angular.module('myApp').
        controller('MyController', MyController);

    function MyController(myFactory) {
        var vm = this,
            someObject = { ... };

        //Invoke public factory functions
        vm.object = myFactory.setObject(someObject);
    }
})();
```

Comment: can you give me example with passing object via $stateprovider

Comment: @VirtuoZ, if that's what is preferred, I would suggest checking the accepted answers in the following threads: 1) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24575491/angular-ui-router-passing-data-beetween-states-with-go-function-does-not-work and 2) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28248236/angular-ui-router-passing-data-between-states-without-url. :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved issue, the problem was in version of angular-ui-router, it jsut didn't work with version that I had, to be more concrete  I got error when I try to add params on state