# Unable to access $state custom properties in $locationChangeStart with next and prev arguments

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

> What i am trying to do

As mentioned in questions title, i want to check authorization and authentication of next routes so i have made custom properties on routes and trying to access them in $locationChageStart.

> Problem i am facing is

the `event` , `next` , `prev/current` arguments are correct but custom properties are returning undefined

**My code**

```
myModule.run(function($rootScope,authService,$state){

        $rootScope.$on("$locationChangeStart",function(e,next,prev){

            console.log(e+","+next+","+prev);  //correct
            console.log(next.reqAuthentication); // returning undefined
            console.log(prev.reqAuthentication); // returning undefined
        });
    })
```

and in Config routes are like

```
           .state('profile.company', {
            url: "/company",
            templateUrl: 'partials/companyprofile.html',
            controller: 'adminCtrl',
            reqAuthentication:true,
            authenticateRole:['a','b',"c"]

        })
        .state('profile.messages', {
            url: "/messages",
            templateUrl: 'partials/chat.html',
            controller: 'adminCtrl',
            reqAuthentication:true,
            authenticateRole:['a','b',"b"]
            })
```

**Note:** I am using ui routes so i think there is some problem i am mixing it up with ngRoute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', 
function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){ ... })
```

if you want to work with states.

More details you can find https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki

Comment: thanks for the answer,i already tried it fromState.reqAuthentication and toState.reqAuthentication both are undefined

Comment: thanks, resolved can you explain whats toParams and fromParams reefer to?

Comment: Maybe I had been quick with toParams and fromParams. You are right need to write fromState.reqAuthentication and toState.reqAuthentication. Because toParams and fromParams allow going to a sibling state that shares parameters specified in a parent state: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19516771/state-go-toparams-not-passed-to-stateparams