# Angular UI router - Pass dynamic data with a route?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a couple of routes/states defined in my application. Consider the standard use case of list view and single view. For my single view, I pass the id as a URL parameter. I want to pass some more data, but not as URL parameters. Can this be done? I use `$state.go` for transitioning to states.

Edit:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('list', {
        url: '/list',
        ...
    })
    .state('single', {
        url: '/single/:id',
        ...
    });
```

I get the `id` in the `$stateParams` in the respective controller, from the URL. But I want to send more dynamic data to this route, without sending it through the URL. How would I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the additional params like this.

```
  state('state_name', {
        url: 'state_url',
        template: '<template></template>',
        params : params
    })
```

You can get the values by using the $state.current

```
$state.current.param
```

Comment: How would I do it when calling state.go?

Comment: You can specify the parameters in $state.go as the second argument (toParams).
Have a look at: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#stategoto--toparams--options

Comment: I think this question should help you..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19516771/state-go-toparams-not-passed-to-stateparams

Comment: Yes! The link is pretty helpful! But what about `ui-sref`, how do I specify the params in `ui-sref`?

Comment: Are you looking for this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25647454/how-to-pass-parameters-using-ui-sref-in-ui-router-to-controller

Comment: It still uses URL arguments, which I don't want! I'm already sending the URL param for the single route. I have updated my description.