# Hidden params when using $state not working - AngularJS, Ionic

Tags: angularjs, url, state, parameters, ionic-framework

I'm a beginner using the ionic framework.

I'm trying to use stateParams with a state but I don't want it to be exposed in the URL.

I could use stateParams when it's added to the URL (url/:param1) but when I tried to declare it under 'params' as mentioned here [ [How to send and retrieve parameters using $state.go toParams and $stateParams?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19516771/state-go-toparams-not-passed-to-stateparams) ] and here [ [AngularJS: Pass an object into a state using ui-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20632255/angularjs-pass-an-object-into-a-state-using-ui-router) ], I get the following error:

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module surveyApp due to:
>   TypeError: undefined is not a function
>       at getArrayMode (http//localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:38251:39)
>       at new Param (http//localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:38224:21)
>       at http//localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:38857:39
>       at forEach (http//localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:8147:20)
>       at Object.stateBuilder.ownParams (http//localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:38856:7)
>       at registerState (http//localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:38975:72)
>       at $StateProvider.state (http//localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:39460:5)
>       at $StateProvider.IonicModule.factory.config.$stateProvider.state (http//localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:45621:31)
>       at http//localhost:8100/js/app.js:88:3
>       at Object.invoke (http//localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:11994:17)
>   http//errors.angularjs.org/1.3.6/$injector/modulerr?p0=surveyApp&p1=TypeEr…3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8100%2Flib%2Fionic%2Fjs%2Fionic.bundle.js%3A11994%3A17)

here's a snippet of my code:

```
.state('tab.mytab', {
    url: '/mytab/:name',
    params: ['item'],
    views: {
        'tab-mytab': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/mytab/item.html',
            controller: 'MyTabCtrl'
        }
    }
})
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array syntax for params that you are using is old and no longer supported since 0.2.12 I believe

You can use

```
params: { item: null}
```

Object as params rather than array.
[Docs](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$stateProvider)