# $stateParams become 'undefined' after passing to the controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I set the  $stateParam by getting a cell value from a table:

```
$scope.tableClick = function() {
    var tr = $('#Table_1').find('tr');
    var id = $(event.target).parent().find("td:first").text();
    $stateParams.engineId == id;
    $state.go('engineselection');
}
```

When I stop the debug at this point. It gives me the engineId value.

This is the router part that I use:

```
$stateProvider.state('engineselection', {
    url : '/engineselection:engineId',
    templateUrl : 'assets/views/engineselection.html',
    controller : 'EngineSelectionCtrl'
})
```

This is what happens in the controller:

```
controllers.controller("EngineSelectionCtrl", 
    ["$scope", "$rootScope", "directiveBinder", '$timeout',    '$stateParams', '$resource', '$location', 'rtmService', '$state',
     function($scope, $rootScope, directiveBinder, $timeout,  $stateParams, $resource, $location, myService, $state) {

myService.loadViewWithEngine(function(id, data) {
    $scope.views = data;
    $scope.$apply();
    $('#loadingViews').spin(false);
});
```

When I stop here before the function and type console $stateParams, it tells me that I have a state parameter named 'engineId' but it is undefined. What should I do to pass the parameter to the controller with its value?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19516771/state-go-toparams-not-passed-to-stateparams

Comment: `var tr = $('#Table_1').find('tr');
    var id = $(event.target).parent().find("td:first").text();` you are working with angular.. please dont do this. you are not **thinking in angular**

Comment: `$stateParams.engineId == id;` is a *comparison* not an *assignment*; you want `$stateParams.engineId = id;`

Comment: @gopinathshiva It only works if you don't use 'url', which is not my case.

Comment: @entre Thanks, but I am a complete starter. Can you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

Worked after I have changed $state.go call like this:

```
$state.go('viewselection', {engineProgramId: id});
```