# Angularjs passing different lenght values as stateParams

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to pass different lengths of values to the same state:

For example

```
<li href="#/app/list/value1">

<li href="#/app/list/value1/value2">
```

In my state I have the following

```
.state('app.list', {
  url: "/list/:passedLow/:passedHigh",
  views: {
    'menuContent': {
      templateUrl: "templates/file.html",
      controller: 'ValueListCtrl'
    }
  }
})
```

Also I have

```
 $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/landing');
```

so when I click on the second link *(i.e, pass two values)* everything works fine. But when I pass the one with the single value "otherwise" takes over and redirects me to the landing page.

So how can I pass variable length values as `$stateParams`?

Comment: I hope you will find the answer here [assigning multiple route names][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19516771/state-go-toparams-not-passed-to-stateparams

Comment: look in the docs...can use wildcards so if a param isn't there it ignores it

Answer (score 0):

There is [a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/WPCgS5cT239u7ueZUqFk?p=preview)

The solution here is to use `params: {}` to define more details about our parameter:

```
params : { passedHigh : { value : null, squash : true } },
```

What we can see, that we instruct UI-Router to expect that there will be param **passedHigh**. Default value is null (could be adjusted). And we say, that it will be skipped (if default) in **url** - `squash: true`

Doc: [$stateProvider](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$stateProvider)

There is a complete state definition

```
.state('app', {
    url: "/app",
    templateUrl: 'tpl.html',
})
.state('app.list', {
    url: "/list/:passedLow/:passedHigh",
    views: {
        'menuContent': {
            templateUrl: "templates/file.html",
            controller: 'ValueListCtrl'
        }
    },
    params: {
        passedHigh: {
            value: null,
            squash: true
        }
    },
})
.state('app.landing', {
    url: "/landing",
    templateUrl: 'tpl.html',
})
```

check it [here in action](http://plnkr.co/edit/WPCgS5cT239u7ueZUqFk?p=preview)