# Angular Routing not working the desired way

Tags: html, angularjs

I am using Angular and trying to route to a page. It works everywhere but in the code below, when I try to route, I see the URL moving to the desired page but comes back to the same page from where it was triggered. I am not sure why is it behaving like this.

This is my HTML from where I call a method

```
<button  ng-click="proposalForm()" >Request</button>
```

In my controller.js, I am just trying to route to a different page. When I click the button, it routes to the proposal page but quickly returns to the same from where I trigger this. Am I missing any? It works for me in all other places.

```
$scope.proposalForm = function() {
    $location.path('/proposal');
}
```

When I try to access this using datatarget, it includes the JSP but when I try to route completely to a different page, it doesn't work. Is there any other way, I can route it to a different JSP.

Here is my router code, It has the correct path for proposal, I am not sure if it is routing to the default for some reason

```js
Bid.config(function($routeProvider) {
    .when('/proposal', {
  templateUrl : '/Bid/proposal',
  controller : 'homeController'
 }).otherwise({
  redirectTo : '/'
 });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the library in your project
 `<script data-require="ui-router@*" data-semver="0.2.8" src="http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>`

and then  config.js

```
.state('proposal', {
          url: '/proposal',
templateUrl: 'templates/proposal.html',
controller: 'NewCtrl'
        });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/auth/login');
```

and in controller

```
app.controller('NavCtrl', function ($scope, $location, $state, Post, Auth) { 

    $scope.create = function() {      
      $state.go("proposal"); 
    };
  });
```

and app.js

```
var abc= angular.module('abc', [
       'ui.router'

]);
```

Comment: Where am I supposed to add the .state reference. Should I include in my router or ?

Comment: u have config file ryt add inside config .state('proposal', {
          url: '/proposal',
templateUrl: 'templates/proposal.html',
controller: 'NewCtrl'
        });

Comment: Yeah In the config, I am currently using the $routeProvider, Do you want me to replace this with $stateProvider and try or should I add this as an additional one..

Comment: change to $stateProvide and check

Comment: for your refrence http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19516771/state-go-toparams-not-passed-to-stateparams

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a Single Page application ( SPA ) using AngularJS , you should use the $state service , not the $location service.
Anyway, the code seems correct syntaxically speaking , maybe you can add the router code ?

Comment: Here is my router code,

Project.config(function($routeProvider) {
.when('/proposal', {
  templateUrl : '/Project/proposal',
  controller : 'homeController'
 }).otherwise({
  redirectTo : '/'
 });
});

I have added the router code in my main post as well