# $state.go not passing parameters

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to pass parameters in my $state.go

Normally elsewhere in the app it is written listing out each parameter as:

```
$state.go('home', {
    stateSet: true,
    code: 'TEST',
    id: 1
    });
```

What I currently need to do and does not seem to be working is:

```
params = {stateSet: true, code: 'TEST', id: 1};
$state.go('home', params);
```

Comment: Is the state definition set up to accept input parameters? See:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19516771/state-go-toparams-not-passed-to-stateparams?rq=1

Comment: the top example is how it is currently setup throughout.Not sure what you mean, would I need to check the router.js? Kind of new to angular/front end work

Comment: actually in the router it is defined to take params